Is there a way to browse, manage and explore media/user uploads along with django-ckeditor-5?
I have installed and configured ckeditor using pip install django-ckeditor-5==0.2.13
Afterwards, i am able to configure a model with field content = CKEditor5Field("content")
I have also followed the instructions as provided on https://pypi.org/project/django-ckeditor-5/ and thus able to get the editor in the Admin view working as show below and upload files:

However, if i remove this uploaded image, it is still in media MEDIA_ROOT directory. So if i want to reuse it, I would like to be able to use some explorer/file browser to see files in MEDIA_ROOT directory and use that.
Some form of File manager solution would be really nice for reusing files and also cleaning up uploaded file.
There is CKFinder available, how can i use that with django-ckeditor-5 ? Or if there are other solutions, i am open to using them.
Thanks in advnace,
